# How to use UnitySingleton to save int value when changing scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to the unity world. I created a soccer goal calculator, but when I change the scene and reopen it, the int value is resetting. Searching the web, I found that I need to use unitySingleton, but I don't understand how.

**Can someone please help me understand how to implement unitySingleton**

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Did you try to use the PlayerPrefs for the task you described?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some code of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int variable resetting when loading another scene in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578293/int-variable-resetting-when-loading-another-scene-in-unity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep up gameobjects through scenes you can use `DontDestroyOnLoad(Object target);` what it does is pretty self explanatory all gameobjects that are targeted by this method are not destroyed when loading a new Scene.

Here is an example code of how you could possibly keep up values between scenes:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example: MonoBehaviour
{
/*this holds reference to the gameobject it self it needs to be static otherwise each 
instance would have a reference to it self.*/
public static Example instance = null;
//a value (can be whatever)
public float counter = 0.0f;

void Awake()
{
    /* if there an already existing Example gameobject (instance isn't null) destroy 
    the others*/
    if (instance != null)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    /*the very first instance is kept as the instance and will run through all the 
    scenes keeping all values until the program is shutdown*/
    else
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject); /*this will keep the gameobject "alive" through all scenes*/
        instance = this; /*instance reference to this gameobject (the first one to exist)*/
    }
}
void Update()
{
  /*adding passing time to counter again this can be any behaviour you want and will 
  keep running through scenes AND the values wont be reset until you shutdown the 
  program*/
  counter += Time.deltaTime;
}
}
```

Thus you have a gameobject that is kept through scenes AND keeps updating values as you wish.

Comment: You should move the checks from `Start` to `Awake`

Comment: thanks, bro! i juste edited the start to awake and attached the script to canvas and that worked!